# oracle nested select query

Tags: sql, database, select, oracle11g

I have this table on oracle db:

[image: Original table]

Can i do nested select query that change the PARENT column to the name associated with it?
like this:

[image: Would like to have table]

I have tried:

```
SELECT PC.ID
,(
  SELECT PC.NAME from PRODUCTS_CATEGORIES PC where PC.PARENT = PC.ID
 )
 ,PC.NAME
  FROM PRODUCTS_CATEGORIES PC
```

and got this error:

```
Error Message: ORA-01427: single-row sub query returns more than one row
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this

```
SELECT PC.ID,
(
   SELECT DISTINCT PC2.NAME from PRODUCTS_CATEGORIES PC2 
   where PC.PARENT = PC2.ID AND PC2.PARENT = 0
 ),
 PC.NAME
 FROM PRODUCTS_CATEGORIES PC
```

OR

```
 SELECT PC.ID,NVL(PC2.NAME,PC.PARENT) PC2_NAME,PC.NAME
  FROM PRODUCTS_CATEGORIES PC 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  (SELECT DISTINCT ID, NAME 
  from PRODUCTS_CATEGORIES WHERE PARENT = 0) PC2 ON PC.PARENT = PC2.ID
```

Comment: A `distinct` doesn't guarantee that only a single row is returned.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, i don't think there will be multiple names for same parent id.

Comment: @rs: Then the distinct is useless.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Not necessarily true. There might be multiple rows with *the same name* - in this case, the DISTINCT would be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

```
select pc.id,
       coalesce(pr.name, 'No Parent') as parent_name,
       pc.name
from products_categories pc
  left join products_categories pr on pc.parent = pr.id;
```

Note that storing `0` as the parent isn't such a good idea. It indicates that you probably don't have a foreign key constraint defined on the `parent` column - which you should. To indicate that no parent is present it's better to use `NULL` (which would also work when you do have a foreign key constraint).

Answer (score 0):

Changing the alias in the subquery to say `PC2` would at least make the query logically easier to read.

```
SELECT PC.ID
,(
  SELECT PC2.NAME from PRODUCTS_CATEGORIES PC2 where PC.PARENT = PC2.ID
 )
 ,PC.NAME
  FROM PRODUCTS_CATEGORIES PC
```

I'm surprised oracle can work out the join since both aliases are `PC`. other than that the puter he don't lie - some products have more than one parent.

You could if you didnt mind, choose the first parent (if that is indeed the problem):

```
SELECT PC.ID
,(
  SELECT PC2.NAME from PRODUCTS_CATEGORIES PC2 where PC.PARENT = PC2.ID 
  AND ROWNUM <= 1
 )
 ,PC.NAME
  FROM PRODUCTS_CATEGORIES PC
```

Comment: oracle doesn't support `TOP`